# Cutscene if player does not press anything for 20 sec

Tags: python, loops, pygame

I need a cutscene to be played while player is afk/not pressing any button. It does not work, unless I press enter (move into menu) and then escape (return to intro picture "press any button"). Video should be played while intro is true every 25 sec. It is just like in N64 games, I will make it random cutscene between AI later. Maybe somebody redone generic N64 games already? If it is easier with other platforms, I will switch from pycharm.

```
    def fight_video():
      fight_number = random.randrange(1, 3)
      if fight_number == 1:
          fight1.preview()
      elif fight_number == 2:
          fight2.preview()
      elif fight_number == 3:
          fight3.preview()
      pg.display.update()

   def gameLoop():
    while not gk["gameExit"]:
        time_passed = 0
        dt = clock.tick()
        time_passed += dt
        if time_passed > 25000:
            fight_video()
            time_passed == 0
        while gk["intro"]:
            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            title_screen(intro_picture)
            screen_message("Press any key to start", white, black, 3, True, True, size="large")
            pg.display.update()
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    pg.quit()
                    quit()
                if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                        gk['gameExit'] = True
                        quit()
                    if event.key == pg.K_KP_ENTER:
                        gk['menu'] = True
                        gk['intro'] = False
        while gk['menu']:
            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            screen_message("Choose mode", white, green, 3, False, True, size="large")
            pg.display.update()
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    pg.quit()
                    quit()
                if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                        gk['intro'] = True
                        gk['menu'] = False
gameLoop()
pg.quit()
```